# Fixed width listings columns without extra spaces after copy from pdf

Tags: beamer, spacing, listings, copy-paste

I would like the code listings from my Beamer slides to have the same spacing after having been copied from the pdf, and pasted into a text editor. I have been working with the `columns` option of the `lstset` macro from the `listings` package.

If I use `columns=fixed`, the code listings in the pdf have the alignment I want, just as they appear in the latex. Alas, when the text of the code listing is copied (from e.g. Evince or Acrobat Reader) and pasted into a text editor, the result is malformed, or additional spaces are inserted; often around punctuation marks.

If I use `columns=flexible` or `columns=fullflexible`, the text appears much better in the text editor (apart from absence of space indentation at the start of lines), but now the code listing in the pdf does not have the alignment that I have prepared in the latex file.

For example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  language=C++,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  upquote=true,
  columns=fixed,
%  columns=flexible,
%  columns=fullflexible,
  frame=single,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{C++ Example}

\begin{lstlisting}
void oload(int i)    { std::cout << i << std::endl; }
void oload(float f)  { std::cout << f << std::endl; }
void oload(double d) { std::cout << d << std::endl; }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int    i = 9;
  float  f = 3.14f;
  double d = 3.14;
  oload(i);
  oload(f);
  oload(d);
  return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

With `columns=fixed` the resulting text copied from the pdf generated through the latex above is garbled and will not compile:

```cpp
void oload ( int i )
{ std :: cout << i << std :: endl ; }
void oload ( float f ) { std :: cout << f << std :: endl ; }
void oload ( double d ) { std :: cout << d << std :: endl ; }
int main ( int
{
int
i =
float f =
double d =
oload ( i );
oload ( f );
oload ( d );
return 0;
}
argc , char * argv [])
9;
3.14 f ;
3.14;
```

Meanwhile, with `columns=fullflexible`, the text from the pdf is passable, and will compile, but the code listing in the pdf does not maintain the original use of multiple spaces; for example, the braces and statements within the 3 original `oload` function definitions do not align:

```cpp
void oload(int i) { std::cout << i << std::endl; }
void oload(float f) { std::cout << f << std::endl; }
void oload(double d) { std::cout << d << std::endl; }
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int i = 9;
float f = 3.14f;
double d = 3.14;
oload(i);
oload(f);
oload(d);
return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to have a fixed width listings for columns, without the extra spaces/malformation after copying from the pdf?

Comment: If you need the source code to be exactly the same, don't rely on copying from the pdf, but attach the source file, e.g. https://www.ctan.org/pkg/attachfile2

Comment: I would not choose that approach. My slides have many small examples. Users often try to copy and paste from them. I see this is a reasonable thing for them to want to do.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/61701/383391

Comment: Some books, like the LaTeX Companion, avoid the problem by providing their examples on github https://github.com/FrankMittelbach/tlc3-examples

Comment: I can imagine there are lots of workarounds. Thanks for all your input @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Comment: Copy and paste of code is not reliable. It gets  better if you tag the PDF and add real space chars but even then you can't be sure to get the right result (and tagging a beamer document is currently quite difficult anyway). As @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz wrote: attach the code. For small chunks you can try the accsupp package.